# Programatically enter password on encrypted pdf file using PDFsharp C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I need to open a secured password protected PDF files programatically in  ASP.NET using C#

I don't want to enter the password manually when it opens.
When the file is downloaded to the local drive it must ask the password to download or print the file.

I am using **PDFsharp**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the password in the call to `PdfReader.Open` to open the document. You can then create an unprotected copy of the PDF, e.g. to print it without password prompt.

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/UnprotectDocument-sample.ashx

Comment: Here I want to make protected copy of pdf while opening of protected copy in my portal that time i don't want to enter password manually. What should i do?

Comment: Either create an unprotected temporary file (this is where PDFsharp may help) or find a viewer that allows passing passwords programmatically (since PDFsharp is not a viewer, you will need a third-party tool).

Comment: Is there any suggestions for third party viewer tools that allow to enter password programmatically?

Comment: No recommendation. If I understand the setup correctly, you want to show the PDF file in a browser on a client computer and you want to pass the password programmatically to the viewer running on the client computer. First problem: the browser decides which viewer will be used for PDF. Second problem: there is no standard way to pass additional data to that viewer.

Comment: Yeah...you understand correctly. Thank you for support